# How do I display a Polymer webcomponent properly in an angularDart-centred app?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart

I have a Polymer PaperButton working in a AnguarDart app:  I click it, and it calls a function.  The css correctly gives it its colour. But the button is small, and does not appear as a "proper" polymer PaperButton.

In my component I include:

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:web_components/web_components.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_button.dart';
```

```
<paper-button (click)="wow()" raised > Wow!</paper-button>
```

The button size is the size of a standard html button, no ink etc. The angular2 buttons are the Material size.

And in index.html I include:

```
<script src="packages/web_components/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
```

What am I missing please?

Comment: What's the HTML looking like?

Comment: Actually I don't get from the question what the problem is. What is the actual and expected behavior?

Comment: Hi. The button size is the size of a standard html button, no ink etc. The angular2 buttons are the Material size.

Comment: <paper-button (click)="wow()" raised > Wow!</paper-button>

Comment: Do you have an other component working inside your app ? It looks like you did not init Polymer with `initPolymer` function in you main https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/wiki/registration-and-lifecycle